# How can a user will be qualified to receive email from alert@salesforce.com?

Tags: email-alert, notification

How can a user will be qualified to receive email from alert@salesforce.com? I want to add other users to receive those email coming from alert@salesforce.com. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

On the user record in salesforce there are a number of checkboxes to enable the emailing of alerts from Salesforce (eg Apex alerts etc)